# Trouble installing MySQL

Tags: mysql, nginx

I am following this guide, [How to set up a web server on the Raspberry Pi](https://thepi.io/how-to-set-up-a-web-server-on-the-raspberry-pi/). I am using a Pi 400 so I skipped step 1.

Step 2 involved running:

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

which was successful. Now if I re-run the command I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nginx is already the newest version (1.18.0-6.1+deb11u3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbasicusageenvironment1 libfuse2 libgroupsock8 liblivemedia77
  libusageenvironment3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 275 not upgraded.
```

In step 3 I encountered a problem:

First I ran

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

which returned

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mariadb-server-10.0

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

I tried following some online guides but all of them fail.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use apt-cache to look for likely candidates.

```
apt-cache search mysql-server
mariadb-server-10.5 - MariaDB database server binaries
mariadb-server-core-10.5 - MariaDB database core server files
default-mysql-server - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup (metapackage)
default-mysql-server-core - MySQL database server binaries (metapackage)
```

So try

`sudo apt install default-mysql-server`

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB has replaced MySQL and it is better. You can use the above mentioned

```
sudo apt install default-mysql-server
```

command to install MySQL but if you want to go with MariaDB then use the command

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y
```

for that. Hope it helps.