# Trouble installing php5

Tags: php

I am following this guide, [How to set up a web server on the Raspberry Pi](https://thepi.io/how-to-set-up-a-web-server-on-the-raspberry-pi/). I am using a Pi 400 so I skipped step 1.

Step 2 involved running;

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

which was successful. Now if I re-run the command I get;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nginx is already the newest version (1.18.0-6.1+deb11u3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbasicusageenvironment1 libfuse2 libgroupsock8 liblivemedia77
  libusageenvironment3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 275 not upgraded.
```

In step 3 I encountered a problem;

First I ran

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

returned

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mariadb-server-10.0

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

I used:

```
sudo apt install default-mysql-server
```

and it downloaded.

Now on step 4,

> Install PHP

tells me to use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysql
```

but I get the same "Package is not available" message like last time.

What is the solution?

Comment: Mysql isn't available anymore. Install MariaDB instad

Comment: When it says package is not available, that means what it says it means. It is common for that to happen. What I do, I search up the error with the package name then find an alternative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing MySQL](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/140841/trouble-installing-mysql)

Comment: Don't use 5 year old tutorials from random websites. Try official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are trying to follow an old tutorial. PHP 5 was released around 2016 or 2017. The latest version of PHP is 8.

The command to install PHP is

```
sudo apt-get install php -y
```